# Is this a reasonable way to make use of range based for loops?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering recently what the requirements were for range based for loops in c++11, as I had only ever seen examples of intended usage:

```
for (auto person : people)
{
  cout << person.name << endl;
}
```

But given that a container need only have begin and end methods, but need not contain anything at all, would the below be considered 'bad practice' in any way?  If nothing else, it is a fresh answer if someone asks you for a Fibonacci sequence in an interview!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct FibItr
{
    FibItr(int cur = 1, int prev = 0) : mCur(cur), mPrev(prev) {}
    FibItr & operator++()
    {
        mCur += mPrev;
        mPrev = mCur - mPrev;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator*(){ return mCur; }

    bool operator!=(const FibItr & _rhs)
    {
        return mCur != _rhs.mCur || mPrev != _rhs.mPrev;
    }   

    unsigned int mCur, mPrev;
};

struct Fib
{
    FibItr begin() { return FibItr(); }
    FibItr end() { return FibItr(0, 0); }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{   
    for (auto num : Fib())
    {
        cout << num << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite find an *infinite loop* something reasonable... but that's just me.

Comment: @David Why not? There’s always `break` and infinite sequences as generators are entirely reasonable.

Comment: I would put in the effort to make `FibItr` a proper ForwardIterator.  One way would be to inherit `std::iterator` and implement more methods like `operator==`, `operator->`, `operator++(int)`.  Another way: use `boost::iterator_facade`.

Comment: Of course, it's a perfectly reasonable way. The last time somebody thought of iterators as things to walk over a container was when everybody still thought templates were there to parameterize container types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not really about the `auto for-loop` but if it is reasonable to implement stranger kind of iterators. While there are corner-cases you can make a perfect good argument for implementing some operations as iterators (memoized fibonacci being a good example).

There are whole libraries devoted to turning iterators in something more, so some other people also think it is a good idea.

As an aside: Implementing an iterator is tricky business, which is why methods like this should be used with care. [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) is a good set of helpers that can make that easier.

Comment: Yep that's about right - but really in conjunction with the auto for loops. Off the top, I could imagine a set of classes which represent tables in a database, each with a common base class to handle the bulk of begin()/end(), and then using this type of pattern to more succinctly get data from whatever table, file, etc you are interested in, with some control over when/how much data is loaded, based on an optional buffer size: `for (auto customer : Customers(100))` would then read from the Customers table in blocks of 100 - it seems really intuitive/simple.